# Is it a bad idea to do Authorization Code URI redirect in a frontchannel?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, web-frontend

I am currently writing an OAuth 2.0 system which contains an authentication server frontend which contains logic that displays the result of a login (success or fail) by sending the request as a XMLHTMLRequest in JavaScript, parsing the response from the backend, and injecting the status back to the DOM (as opposed to sending a POST `form` direclty in HTML via a submit action without using XMLHTTPRequest).

In order to retain this authorization server UI behavior while also going to the next step of OAuth 2.0, I was going to use something like inside the authorization server frontend JavaScript:

```js
window.location.href = 'client.tld/callback?authorization_code=abc123'
```

I understand that once the client get's the authorization code, they need to make the request to get the access code via a secure backchannel call (backend to backend). However, I could not find any definitive information to find out whether doing the redirect to the authorization code callback to the client via frontchannel (i.e. redirect with authorization code via frontend JavaScript code) would be insecure.

Would this open up a security vulnerability compared with redirecting in the backend of the authorization server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, it doesn't matter how you make the redirect itself. But an authorization code is a sensitive information and I would rather avoid working with it in JavaScript if it's not really necessary. It just creates one more possibility to attack the system that should have security as its first priority - your frontend can have some bugs that could be misused.